# Azure APIM Policy to authenticate App Configuration service using access keys

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity, azure-app-configuration, apim

I'm trying to authenticate Azure App Configuration Service with access keys in APIM policies.
Can someone help how we can authenticate Azure App Configuration Service using Access keys in APIM policies.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the HMAC authentication as explained in the document below. There are code samples in a variety of languages in that doc too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/rest-api-authentication-hmac